# upgrade ubuntu without upgrading plasma4

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade to the newest version of ubuntu but I don't want plasma5 KDE desktop. is there a way to do the upgrade without sorting through a few thousand packages and dependencies?

my question is different because I want to prevent the upgrade of the entire desktop environment, but allow the base system to upgrade.this involves several hundred files and dependencies that keep trying to remove the entire desktop.
(the change from plasma 4 to plasma 5 a completely new desktop evnroment, like going from kde to gnome).

look at my answer this is not a duplicate question. this process involved 600 packages. sorting by hand took 3 hours.and would be impossible to do by command line holds

Comment: @RecursiveCursive: I don't think the Ubuntu release upgrader can deal with held packages.

Answer (score 1):

well i did it manually on a test drive using aptitude. for those that are interested the result is:

3 hours mucking through dependencies

1107 packages updated

633  packages held

36   packages removed

24   packages added

7    packages recommended by others.

the system seems stable, I give it a few days testing before doing it to may main system.

I started by holding all packages that had plasma in the name. then told aptitude to mark all upgradable. from there it was hours of holding back broken package, for awhile every fix cause 5 more breaks. you have to go through the package list again and again, until all are resolved.
in the end, all KDE programs were held back (this I half expected), python was held back, xorg was held back, hundred of libraries were held back.
Now that I have the major upgrade done, it nay be possible to go back and wring out some more updates, but the dependency chains on some packages are so long tht i doubt there will be many.

Comment: Can you give more details?  The way this answer is written, it just says that you did it, but not how.

Comment: @organic -- details added as you requested.